# Android app closes when the orientation is changed

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my app to run in the portrait view so I made the following changes in the android manifest file.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

It stays in the portrait view for a second and then it closes.. I had assumed this is the only change i had to make..but i also added this but it isnt working

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Am i missing something?

```
     <activity android:name=".Menu" android:label="COMEDY TRIVIA"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="nik.trivia.MENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: By "closes" do you mean force-quits? then you need to look in the log to see details of the error. You, and we, can't do much to figure it out without such information.

Comment: No..just a normal termination of the app

Comment: Is the keyboard visible?  You may need to specify `keyboardHidden` in `configChanges` as well, since I think it will hide and re-show when you change orientation.

Comment: also its working on my phone (sony ericsson xperia) but not on the emmulator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this adding `android:configChanges` to your `AndroidManifest` file in the `activity tag`

```
<activity android:name=".Fourth" android:label="Fourth" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Hope this works for you.